# Django admin slow using TabularInline with many to many field

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to use Django admin to visualize all samples in one request. It works, but it is really slow. I tried to use `prefetch`, `formset`, `raw_id_fields`, and `readonly_fields` with no luck. It is still very slow when I load more than 10 samples. I'm having a N+1 problem here. I checked on Django debug toolbar and it makes a query for each sample in that request.

Here are my models:

```
# This is where the sample has all information
class Inventory(models.Model):
    sample_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self.sample_id)

# Intermediate model
class SampleRequestInventory(models.Model):
    sample = models.ForeignKey("Inventory", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    request = models.ForeignKey("SampleRequest", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# This is the request model that I'm looking  
class SampleRequest(models.Model):
    samples = models.ManyToManyField("Inventory", through="SampleRequestInventory")
```

Here are my django admin configuration:

```
class SamplesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SampleRequestInventory
    # raw_id_fields = ('sample',)
    readonly_fields = ('sample',)
    extra = 0

# this formset did not work either
# class MyInlineFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
#      def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, instance=None,
#              save_as_new=False, prefix=None, queryset=None, **kwargs):
#         super(MyInlineFormset, self).__init__(data, files, instance,
#                                           save_as_new, prefix, queryset, **kwargs)
#         self.queryset = SampleRequest.objects.all(). \
#         prefetch_related('samples')

class SampleRequestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # This queryset for prefetching only makes an extra query...
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(SampleRequestAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.prefetch_related('samples')
    # extra settings
    list_display = ('date', 'status',)
    ordering = ('date',)
    # inline that causes the slowness
    inlines = (SamplesInline, )
    # I tried using formset as well, but didn't work
    # formset = MyInlineFormset
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the following to your SamplesInline:

```py
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(SamplesInline, self).get_queryset(request)
    return qs.select_related('sample')
```

The `readonly_fields` in your Inline is causing the extra lookup to satisfy the `__str__` for your `Inventory` class.

Comment: Using `select_related` together with `readonly_fields` works. The bounty can be awarded in 22h. Thanks David! Any idea why with `raw_id_field` does not work? It looks like raw_id_field pulls all the fields...